# Google Developer Tools - Capturing Network Screenshot Recordings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, async-await, developer-tools

Is it possible to download the screenshots captured when activating the 'capture screenshots' button in the Chrome developer tools window?

I know I could screenshot the opened preview, but that seems to defeat the point of it, not to mention that downloading them all at once would be a huge time saver! [image: Capture Network Screenshots]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Chrome developer tool has that functionality. If you are looking to do an import/export for network activities, I suggest [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).